# Como puedo procesar el conjunto de resultados de un stored procedure en sql server para realizar otras acciones?

Tags: sql-server, base-de-datos, stored-procedure, cursor

tengo un procedimiento almacenado que se ejecuta en un servidor vinculado, el cual devuelve un conjunto de filas. Necesito procesar en mi servidor esos datos, para por ejemplo insertar filas en una tabla cuando no existan, o actualizarlas cuando ya existan.

El sp en el servidor vinculado es algo parecido a:

```
 CREATE PROCEDURE  sp_trabajosdelDia @centro TINYINT , @servicio SMALLINT
AS

SELECT  t.id , col2,col3,col4, hora
FROM    Trabajos t 
        INNER JOIN otra_tabla ev on ev.id= t.Idforanea
WHERE   CONVERT(VARCHAR,t.fecha,23) = CONVERT(VARCHAR, GETDATE(),23)
        AND t.IdCentroAtencion = @centro
        AND t.IdServicio = @servicio
        ORDER by t.hora
```

Lo simplifiqué un poco, porque el inconveniente no tiene mucho que ver con el sp.
Lo mas importante es el id que obtengo en ese sp.

Luego en mi servidor estoy creando un sp, que ejecute el sp anterior y utilice los datos obtenidos

```
    CREATE PROCEDURE  sp_trabajos @c tinyint, @s smallint
as

exec SERVIDORVINCULADO.DBREMOTA.sp_trabajosdelDia @c, @s
```

Necesito, en este ultimo sp procesar los datos obtenidos del procedimiento remoto para poder realizar inserciones y actualizaciones de tablas en mi servidor.

He pensado en usar un cursor, pero los resultados los obtengo si o si a traves del un stored procedure, por politicas de la empresa.
Podría usar tablas temporales en el sp? como podría hacerlo?
Gracias!

Answer (score 1):

El uso de bucles no es un buen camino en TSQL, y siempre existen otras alternativas.

```
Create procedure sp_trabajosDelDia 
(
    @centro tinyint, 
    @servicio smallint
)
As
Begin
    Declare @time  time(0)= Getdate();
    
    -- El origen de los datos no importa para este ejercicio.
    Select 1 as id,
            @centro as col2, 
            @servicio as col3,
            @time; 
    
End;
```

Este es la declaración del procedimiento remoto, realmente se devuelve lo que se le pasa como parámetro, mas @time, que es la hora de ejecución. Para el escenario es suficiente.

```
Create Table servicio (
    id int primary key, 
    col2 tinyint,
    col3 smallint,
    fecha time);
```

La tabla donde insertamos o actualizamos desde el procedure "remoto".

```
Create procedure sp_trabajos 
(
    @c tinyInt, 
    @s smallint
)
As
Begin
    Declare @table table 
    (id int, col2 tinyint, col3 smallint, fecha time);

    Insert @table (id, col2, col3, fecha)
    exec dbo.sp_trabajosDelDia @c, @s;

    -- disponemos de todo lo que retorna en procedimiento 
    -- remoto en la variable tipo tabla @table

    -- Ahora hacemos un Merge a nuestra tabla.

    Merge dbo.Servicio as Target
    using (Select id, col2, col3, fecha
            From @table)
    as Source (id, col2, col3, fecha)
    On target.id = source.id -- unimos ambos conjuntos
    When Matched Then 
    Update
        Set
            col2 = source.col2,
            col3 = source.col3,
            fecha = source.fecha
    When Not Matched by Target Then
        Insert (id, col2, col3, fecha)
        Values
        (source.id, 
        source.col2,
        source.col3,
        source.fecha);
End
```

El procedimiento, que invoca al procedure remoto, recogiendo los resultados de este en una ***variable tipo Tabla***.

Luego usando la sentencia **Merge**, inserta o actualiza en función del origen recogido en esa variable.

Su ejecución. Dado que no hay ningún registro en la tabla, la primera vez será una inserción.

```
Exec dbo.sp_trabajos 1, 1
```

El resultado.

[image: Res]

Otras veces.

```
Exec dbo.sp_trabajos 2, 1
```

[image: Res2]

Se puede ver lo que ocurre con la actualización.

Pero esta solución es de conjuntos y no bucles, por tanto si el origen devuelve varias filas también es funcional.

Hacemos una pequeña trampa en el procedure de origen para que nos devuelva más filas. Para actualizar e insertar a la vez.

```
Create or alter procedure sp_trabajosDelDia 
(
    @centro tinyint, 
    @servicio smallint
)
As
Begin
    Declare @time  time(0)= Getdate();
    
    -- El origen de los datos no importa para este ejercicio.
    With cte as (
        Select t.n from (values(1),(2),(3),(4),(5))T(n)
    )
    Select  cte.n as id,
            @centro as col2, 
            @servicio as col3,
            @time
            From (values(1))T(m)
                Cross join cte 
    
End;
```

Ahora la invocación a este procedure nos devuelve 5 filas desde el id 1 al 5.

LLamamos a sp_trabajos para ver que ocurre en la tabla destino.

```
Exec dbo.sp_trabajos 3, 1

select * from dbo.servicio
```

[image: Res3]

El registro de id=1 se ha visto actualizado, y los registros 2,3,4 y 5 se han insertado.

[Merge](https://javifer2.wordpress.com/2019/10/04/merge-upsert-insertar-o-actualizar-en-una-sola-sentencia/)

[Insertar en tabla temporal el resultado de un procedure](https://javifer2.wordpress.com/2020/08/27/insert-temp-table-result-procedure/)

Comment: Hola @Javi fer2. Muchas gracias,Excelente  la explicación. Voy a trabajar con tu aporte!

Comment: Estuve usando tu respuesta para mi caso, y me surge una pregunta, en el caso de que no quiera insertar todas las columnas del sp remoto, solo algunas, como deberia hacer? pero si mostrar todo el conjunto de resultados.

Comment: Pues mencionar en la sentencia Merge, solo las columnas que quieras insertar. `Merge ..... When Not Matched by Target Then Insert (id, fecha)Values(source.id, source.fecha);`

Comment: si, a esa conclusión llegué y logré escribir el codigo. No logro poder ejecutarlo, debido a un error que dice "EL proveedor OLE DB "SQLNCLI11 del servidor vinculado devolvió el mensaje 'No transaction is active'    el proveedor del servidor vinclado no pudo iniciar una transaccion distribuida " Revise las configuraciones que encontre investigando, pero todo parece estar correcto. Sabrias decirme donde podria estar la falla?

Comment: No entiendo porque al llamar al procedimiento remoto desde mi procedimiento local funciona correctamente, cuando intento procesar los resultados del sp remoto en mi sp local me arroja el error de que el servidor vinculado no puede iniciar una transaccion, si no estoy intentando ejecutar ninguna transaccion en el servidor vinculado.